# MiKTeX 21.7: Difference between pdflatex.exe and miktex-pdflatex.exe

Tags: pdftex, miktex

For a while I was struggling with an error in the pdf-output of one of my documents. On one page, half of the text in a line was missing. On the next line, the text just continued without the missing part. Unfortunately, I did not manage to build a minimal working example, as the problem always disappeared when any random parts of the approx. 150 preceding pages were missing.

Finally, I found out that my Texmaker 5.0.4 was using the executable pdflatex.exe in the MiKTeX binary-path (User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe). TeXworks 0.6.6, which came with the MiKTeX distribution, instead was using miktex-pdftex.exe (User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-pdftex.exe) with the argument "-undump=pdflatex" and the compiled pdf did not show the problem described above. So my solution to the problem was adopting the binary path and the arguments of TeXworks in Texmaker and using miktex-pdftex.exe instead of pdflatex.exe.

Everything is fine now, but I am wondering what the difference between the behaviour of the two executables is? In the MiKTex documentation it seems, as only the "miktex-..." variants are documented. So can it be concluded that only those shall be used? But why are the variants without "miktex-...", like pdflatex.exe then also part of the distribution?

Because of curiosity, it would be great if someone could help me with bringing some light to those questions.

Comment: as user you should normally use `pdflatex` (it will call miktex-pdftex internally).

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. Interestingly, the output pdf changed when calling miktex-pdftex.exe or miktex-pdflatex.exe instead of pdflatex.exe. That made me wonder. So it seems like there might be some problem with my local installation of MikTeX.

Comment: compare the log-files of both compilations (it is possible that the search pathes are different, but if this is the problem you should try to find out how to correct the pdflatex compilation as that it the normal one).

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification. Besides the timestamp, a diff on the log-files only shows different usages of TeX's memory (differences in: available string characters, used and available words of memory, available words of font info) and a different size of the compiled pdf-file (pdflatex.exe's output is 10 bytes larger than miktex-pdftex.exe's output). So I am still a bit confused, but will try solving the problem of the `pdflatex` compilation then.